# Как задать фокус элементу Angular kendo scrollview при загрузке

Tags: typescript, angular, kendo

У меня есть компонент scrollview для отображения картинок, проблема следующая, при открытии view на просмотр картинок нельзя сразу перелистывать картинки стрелками на клавиатуре, а только после нажатия мышкой на контрол. Как программно устанавливать фокус?

```
@ViewChild('scrollView') element: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
  @Input() images: NewsMedia[] = [];

  public mediaUrl = '';

  constructor(private urlProvider: UrlProviderService) {
    this.mediaUrl = urlProvider.mediaUrl + 'media?id=';
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.setFocus();
  }

  public setFocus(): void {
    this.element?.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Comment: ngAfterViewInit? Смотрели что попадает в this.element?

Comment: @InDevX да, попадает нужный мне div на который я хочу фокус установить.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить focus() на click() (`this.element?.nativeElement.click();`)

Comment: @InDevX, результат прежний)

Comment: а через dispatchEvent - `const event = new MouseEvent('click', { view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true }); this.element?.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);` ?

Comment: @InDevX, тоже не получается.

Comment: Тогда добавьте работающий пример